# Show that $e^{x+2y}$ is differentiable in $(2,2)$ using the definition of differentiability

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I kind of understand the rough technique, but the above example was to hard for me. I understand that to show that a function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at point $(a,b)$ I have to show:
$$
\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}\frac{f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)-f_x'(a,b)h-f_y'(a,b)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0
$$
So with $(a,b)=(2,2)$ and $f(x,y)=e^{x+2y}$, I get:
$$
e^6\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}\frac{e^{h+2k}-1-(h+2k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}
$$
Several uninteresting intermediate calculations have been omitted. Like $f_x'(2,2)=e^6$ and $f_y'(2,2)=2e^6$. 
I don't know how to continue here. I have attempted the substitution $x=h+2k$, $y=h-2k$ which gives me:
$$
4e^6\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{e^x-1-x}{\sqrt{5x^2+5y^2+6xy}}$$
In P.F:
$$
4e^6\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{e^{r\cos\theta}-r\cos\theta-1}{\sqrt{5r^2+6r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}}
\iff
4e^6\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{e^{r\cos\theta}-r\cos\theta-1}{r\sqrt{5+3\sin2\theta}}
$$
What should I do to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried using the Maclaurin series for $e^x$ with $x=h+2k$?

Comment: No. That probably works, but this exercise is so early in the course that I don't think so advanced methods are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you stop at the expression just above where you said "Several uninteresting..." and put h and k in polar form, i.e. $h=r\cos\theta$ and $k=r\sin\theta$ and also make the substitution $p=h+2k$

The limit then is 
$$\lim_{p \to 0} e^6 (\cos\theta + 2\sin\theta)  \frac{e^p-(1+p)}{p}$$

But $$\lim_{p \to 0} \frac{e^p-(1+p)}{p} = 0$$ (property of exponential function that you can prove by looking at the series expansion of the exponential function, for example).

and the expression involving thetas in parentheses is bounded.  So you have that the limit is zero.

Comment: So first you switch to polar form, then you do the substitution $p = r(\cos\theta + 2\sin\theta)$? Is it allowed to do a substitution like that? If so, it's a good solution! Calculating the limit in $p$ and showing that $\cos\theta + 2\sin\theta$ is bounded should be fairly simple for me.

Comment: Sure.  You can do substitutions (i.e., change variables) any number of times.  In this case, you just have to make sure that $r \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow p \rightarrow 0$, which is true from the definition of $p$.

Comment: I suppose you are right! It just feels foreign to me to stuff the $\theta$ and $r$ into the same variable.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $|h+2k|\leq\sqrt{5}\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$, by Schwarz' inequality. Furthermore, since $\exp$ is differentiable at $6$ with $\exp'(6)=e^6$ there is a function $u\mapsto r(u)$ with $\lim_{u\to0} r(u)=0$ such that
$$e^{6+u}=e^6+e^6\, u+ u\, r(u)\qquad(u\to0)\ .\tag{1}$$
Let $f(x,y):=e^{x+2y}$. Putting $u:=h+2k$ in $(1)$ then gives
$$e^{(2+h)+2(2+k)}=e^{6+h+2k}=e^6+e^6(h+2k)+(h+2k)r(h+2k)\ .$$
It follows that
$${f(2+h,2+k)-f(2,2)-e^6(h+2k)\over\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}={h+2k\over\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}r(h+2k)\ .$$
Here the first factor on the RHS is $\leq\sqrt{5}$ in absolute value, and the second converges to $0$ when $(h,k)\to(0,0)$. This proves that $f$ is differentiable at $(2,2)$, and that $\nabla f(2,2)=(e^6,2e^6)$.

Note that the differentiability of $f$ follows from "general principles", since $f=\exp\circ\,\psi$, whereby both $\exp$ and $\psi:\>(x,y)\mapsto x+2y$ are differentiable.